# Where are the grid-cols-* utilities in bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

they have an example using `d-grid` for buttons

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#block-buttons

with `gap` but.... grid has columns too

where are those utility classes?

tailwindcss has an example:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns

Comment: I have made my answer more specific now. Grid col infos are to be found at the page i mentioned first off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bootstrap CSS Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/css-grid/) will be implemented in Bootstrap only as from version v5.1.0.

[Grid col classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/css-grid/#how-it-works) infos here at that paragraph of the above docs
page:

> Replace .col-* classes with .g-col-* classes. This is because our CSS Grid columns use the grid-column property instead of width.

Comment: ahh great. Do you know any advantages / disadvantages for css grid ? more easy to have more columns than only 12? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/css-grid/#sass

Comment: @Toskan Well, i like especially: 1.that it is very useful to build grids where you can address elements 2-dimensionally (e.g.: element 2nd row & 3rd column).  2. build consistent 2-dimensional grids 3. build responsive layouts without media queries (e.g.: `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));`

Comment: @Toskan Oh, you meant Bootstraps CSS Gridimplementation. Sorry, i myself haven't been using Bootstrap CSS Grid so far.